# Installing OpenCV for all conda environments

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 system with an Anaconda installation. I want to compile and install OpenCV 3.3 and use also the Python bindings. I used the following CMake command:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D D WITH_FFMPEG=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/guel/anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/python -D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=/home/guel/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/guel/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages -DWITH_EIGEN=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_cudalegacy=OFF ..`

The command does the job but then, of course, OpenCV is installed only for a specific conda environment that I created. However, I want to be able to use it also from different environments without having to go through the compilation for each and every environment. Is there a way to achieve that in a simple way? Since the OpenCv libraries are actually installed in `/usr/local`, I can imagine that there must be a simple way to link the libraries to each new conda enviroment but I couldn't figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

`OpenCV 3.3` for `python 2.7 and 3.6` on `linux` are available from `conda repository`. You may not need to compile yourself. Just use `conda command` to install it to your environement.

See this

1. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv for the commands.

   - `conda install -c conda-forge -n env opencv` or
   - `conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken -n env opencv`
   - where `env` is your `conda virtual environment name`
2. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv/files for detailed files on python version and OS.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

So you are providing the python package and library path to environment specific location, in order to make it available environment try using the anaconda/bin and lib path. Can't make it as a comment due to low reputation.